# PHP Error: Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP script that is producing the following error:

Only variables should be passed by reference

Here is the line of code giving the problem:

```
if (strpos($config_disabled,end(explode(".", $lfile)))) { ?>
```

Cannot figure out how to change it to stop giving the error. I have tried changing it a few times with no luck. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance!

Here is the full piece of code:

```
 // EDIT
if ($page == "edit") { ?>
    <h2>Edit &ldquo;<a href="<?php echo $filename; ?>"><?php echo $filename; ?></a>&rdquo;</h2>
    <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]; ?>?i=<?php echo substr($_GET["f"],0,strrpos($_GET["f"],"/")); ?>" class="back">Back</a>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]; ?>?f=<?php echo $filename; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="sessionid" value="<?php echo session_id(); ?>" />
        <?php $lfile = strtolower($filename);
        if (strpos($config_disabled,end(explode(".", $lfile)))) { ?>
            <p>
                <textarea name="content" class="textinput disabled" cols="70" rows="25" disabled="disabled">Disabled.</textarea>
            </p>
            <p class="buttons_right">
                <input type="submit" class="button" name="save_file" value="Save" 
                disabled="disabled" />
        <?php } else { ?>
```

Comment: Store the value of _end(explode(".", $lfile))_ into a _$variable_ before passing it to _strpos()_

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  It passes $myExplode by reference to end.

```
$myExplode = explode(".", $lfile);
if (strpos($config_disabled,end($myExplode))) {
    //code here
}
```

I'd recommend reading up on pass by reference:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: That didn't work - and this isn't a duplicate question - The other person had the same error but it was caused by something different.